# Spring AOP Parameterized Annotation

Tags: java, spring, aop, aspectj

I am new to spring AOP and struggling to achieve the following.

I want to define an annotation @RequirePermission which accepts a parameter String or enum and based on that string/enum I will do some calculations in advice. So, any method defined in Controller having @RequiredPermissions should be validated first. Here is my code so far.

Aspect:

```
package com.myapp.aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import com.myapp.security.RequirePermissionType;
import com.myapp.security.RequirePermission;
@Aspect
public class RequirePermissionAspect {

    @Pointcut("within(@org.springframework.stereotype.Controller *)")
    public void controllerBean() {}

    @Pointcut("execution(@com.myapp.security.RequirePermission * com.myapp.controller.*.*(..))")
    public void methodPointcut() {}

    @Before("controllerBean() && methodPointcut() ")
    public void afterMethodInControllerClass(com.myapp.security.RequirePermissionType name) {
        System.out.println("before advice..");
        System.out.println("before advice.."+name.name());
    }
```

Annotation:

```
package com.myapp.security;

public enum RequirePermissionType {
    VIEW, MANAGE, IMPORT, SUPER;
}

@Documented
@Target(ElementType.METHOD )
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Inherited
public @interface RequirePermission {
    /**
     * 
     * @return
     */
    RequirePermissionType name() default RequirePermissionType.VIEW ;
}
```

Now if use the annotation in controller method as below the code works:

```
    @RequestMapping(value={"create"})
    @RequirePermission
    public String createRegion(Model model){
    }
```

But the following does not work:

```
    @RequestMapping(value={"create"})
    @RequirePermission(name=RequirePermissionType.VIEW)
    public String createRegion(Model model){
    }
```

Any one could guide me what I am missing and how do I achieve this.

Comment: anyhow, got it working using this
`@Pointcut("execution(@com.gdev.vim.security.RequirePermission * com.gdev.vim.controller.*.*(..)) && @annotation(name)")`

Comment: :Then please share you Answer

Comment: Changed code is as below.
`@Pointcut("execution(@com.myapp.security.RequirePermission * com.myapp.controller.*.*(..)) && @annotation(name)")
    public void methodPointcut(com.myapp.security.RequirePermission name) {}

    @Before("controllerBean() && methodPointcut(name) ")
    public void afterMethodInControllerClass(com.myapp.security.RequirePermissionType name) {
        System.out.println("before advice..");
        System.out.println("before advice.."+name.name());
    }`

Comment: I meant to say post your answer in the below box

Answer (score 1):

@vamslip here is the updated aspect class. Rest all stays the same.
Updated Aspect:

```
package com.myapp.aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import com.myapp.security.RequirePermissionType;
import com.myapp.security.RequirePermission;
@Aspect
public class RequirePermissionAspect {

@Pointcut("within(@org.springframework.stereotype.Controller *)")
public void controllerBean() {}

@Pointcut("execution(@com.myapp.security.RequirePermission * com.myapp.controller.*.*(..)) && @annotation(name)") 
public void methodPointcut(com.myapp.security.RequirePermission name) {} 

@Before("controllerBean() && methodPointcut(name) ") 
public void afterMethodInControllerClass(com.myapp.security.RequirePermissionType name) { 
    System.out.println("before advice.."); 
    System.out.println("before advice.."+name.name()); 
}
}
```